# Can I send a message different topics in kafka at runtime depending on the load?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have 5 defined topics, my specific question is there any way in the code to know if a kafka topic is free or is still full to be able to balance the load between topics

In the producer I have to do the function `.send(Topic1, object)`  but if the topic to which I am sending the information is busy or already has to load, how can I know it to change the function to `.send(Topic2, object)`  by means of a conditional?

I do not know if this can be done or that otherwise you can know this. Currently, I plan to use ListenableFuture and with  `future.addCallback`  to know if this process is already done and reassign the topic but I do not see it viable.

Comment: What makes you think that a topic can be full or under load ? All topics use the same hardware under the hood ... so they are either all usable or all are blocked.

Comment: That's the whole point of the messaging middleware: to distinguish producer and consumer and have messages stored in between if consumer is not available. Consider a simple database use case: how you may know if you can insert into the table or not? Please, learn more what is Apache Kafka by itself and what is consumer group, records logs etc. You may use metrics to track a consumer lag, but that's not the way how messaging should be used...

Answer (score 0):

Topics don't have load. Brokers do.

A broker can have leader multiple leader partitions of different topics, which clients cannot control.

Therefore, you cannot guarantee that sending data to a new topic (rather, set of partitions) will have less system/network load than another.

Besides that, if you start sending data to other topics, you lose ordering guarantees in both the produced data and the consumer group for any downstream systems.